# where is the file when use getCacheDir

Tags: android

As I debugged, I found that the GetCacheDir return `/data/data/yourapp/cache/`

But as I store files, I found nothing in that path(with shell),
but in `/sdcard/Android/data/yourapp/cache/`  I found the cache file?
who can tell me why?

Comment: weird! i have never seen this before. do you see anything from the log?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As I debugged, I found that the GetCacheDir return /data/data/yourapp/cache/

That sounds right for [getCacheDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29).

> But as I store files, I found nothing in that path(with shell), but in /sdcard/Android/data/yourapp/cache/ I found the cache file? who can tell me why?

That's what you'd get from [getExternalCacheDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29).

Are you sure you're using the right API call? Did you check the return values of your File operations (are they all successful)? You could try some File functions to check that things are working right. (createNewFile, exists, getAbsolutePath)