# NullPointerException at getCacheDir() android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, singleton

I am trying to clear my app data programmatically. But I get a `NullPointerEXception` with the following code.

Here is my code:-

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private static MyApplication instance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
}

public static MyApplication getInstance(){
    return instance;
}

public void clearApplicationData() {
    File cache = getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if(appDir.exists()){
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for(String s : children){
            if(!s.equals("lib")){
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s +" DELETED *******************");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete();
}
```

}

I get a `NullPointerException` while I try to do :-

```
File cache = getCacheDir();
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How are you calling `clearApplicationData()` and how is the object instantiated? Also please post the stacktrace.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957094/where-is-the-file-when-use-getcachedir

Comment: I think you are wrong about where the exception is being thrown. Please check it again. maybe debug the code and go over each line. The reason I think this way is that it doesn't make sense that this line would cause any problem here.

Comment: call with the refernce of context will solve your issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
   File cache = mContext.getCacheDir();
```

i.e. rewrite `clearApplicationData` function and pass context of activity  because `getCacheDir()` function need context

```
public void clearApplicationData(Context mContext) {
    File cache = mContext.getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if(appDir.exists()){
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for(String s : children){
            if(!s.equals("lib")){
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s +" DELETED *******************");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getCacheDir should work fine in his case, since Applicaiton extends Context , and it's the same context you will get : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html . in fact, it's perfectly safe to do it using any Context class.

Comment: @androiddeveloper thanks to informing,edited my answer with second option.

Answer (score 5):

try below code:-

```
File cache = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
```

this error occur because `getCacheDir()` function need context of application.

Comment: getCacheDir should work fine in his case, since Applicaiton extends Context , and it's the same context you will get : developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html . in fact, it's perfectly safe to do it using any Context class, and not just application-context

Answer (score 1):

I think the bug is because you haven't caused the class to be the real Application class to be used.

Check the manifest, that the "android:name" attribute of the "application" tag is set correctly to reference to this class.

In order to check that it get initialized, write to the log in the "onCreate()" method.

In addition, you should only call "clearApplicationData()" by using : "MyApplication getInstance()" first , or by using "((MyApplication )getApplicationContext())" .

Also, note that this "design pattern" of the application context works on 99% of the cases. the only case it won't work is , when you have a content provider, since the application class won't be initialized in this case.

If that's not the reason for the bug, try to debug the code and see that it really goes to this line and crashes there.