# Correct way to store temp files to be shared in Android

Tags: android

I'm currently using [`getExternalCacheDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()) in my app that downloads a file to work with and also share with other apps (email as attachment, whatsapp etc).

It's working fine but I'm not sure if this is right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may save local file inside your app directory and use share intent. May be this solution can help:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri file = Uri.parse(path);
sharingIntent.setType("*/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share file"));
```

All of such file manipulations are only app specific. But, may be http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29 can help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6916553/1979882

Comment: the question is in fact how to save the file, now how to share. How do I get the app directory that can be read by other apps?

Comment: @Bruno, updated